# COMPARISON: Data Transfer Object vs Dict

Tags: python, oop

What are the pros/cons of each? When would I use one over the other?

Is it more effective to create a DTO object or a regular python dictionary?

I would prefer to use dot notation over dict indexes, but not at the cost of performance.

Comment: What measurement have you done? Edit your question to define what you mean by 'performance'? Ease of use, ease of programming? Ease of 'debugging'? Ease of 'maintenance'? Fastest performance? That so much depends on the code. Which you did not provide. There is no 'one answer', ever, to this 'general question'.

Comment: Modern Machines are so fast that creating objects is not an  important  consideration. Neither is processing them locally as, in a lot of cases, the same internal 'machine code' is used. You need to only consider 'ease of understanding'.